# How to uncheck toggle button in mapbasic?

Tags: cartography, mapinfo, mapbasic

I want to check un check togglebutton but I don't know how to alter using mapbasic. Is there any command to alter it?  I could not find it in MapInfo user guide. I have command:

```
Alter Button
```

But how to use I don't know how to provide Id to buttons?

Comment: Is it a custom button that you have made or one of the MapInfo ones?

Comment: Yes @Nathan I have made costum button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first need to add a ID to your custom button when you create it:

```
Create ButtonPad "Utils" As 
    PushButton 
        HelpMsg "Choose this button to display query dialog" 
        Calling button_sub_proc 
        ID 5000 '' This is the ID for the button
```

Then you can alter the button using:

`Alter Button ID 5000`

You can also do:

`Alter Button button_sub_proc`

button_sub_proc  is the method that the button calls.

Although using the method way, if you have more then one button calling that method they all get updated.

Answer (score 0):

`Alter Button ID xx Uncheck`

Good luck